# Most efficient way to do frequent call to same executable in script

Tags: perl, executable

as part of a project I work on, we're reusing a Perl script that loops on certain simple tasks. The problem arises from the fact that :

- The script calls a simple executable (basically reads in the registry) but at ~60Hz
- The executable is on a shared drive
- The directory that it's located in is large (~1000 elements)

So basically, even if I call the executable with its full path, it still parses the whole directory to find it each time it's called, which floods the network.

What's the best way to resolve that? Preferences would be not to change the system architecture (keep exe on shared drive), and not bypass it with say reg.exe to maintain compatibility when our exe changes. I'd also prefer not to rewrite the Perl script in something else, but am open to.

Is there a way to load the exe into process memory for repeated execution? Or keep a handle on it? Is there something to do using symbolic links?

Thanks

Comment: Best if the application was rewritten to be server, listening to a pipe/socket/whatever for requests.

Comment: With 60 calls a second (that many, really?) I'd imagine that OS would cache that for sure.  If you think the problem is finding exe on disk, can your script copy the executable to a chosen place at start and then call it from there?

Comment: I do not have control over the application, but I agree that for those needs this would be the best. Also, that's my fallback solution, to copy the file locally... but as I said, ideally we'd stick with the desired architecture so we can move forward with other features.

Comment: I meant that the Perl script copies the exe file for its own use as it starts, so the exe is available to it locally, for faster loading, while it runs (and it removes that copy on end).  Not to really change the architecture.  (This may not be possible to do, of course)

Comment: I suspect a symbolic link will not help since it will still have to find and execute the target file. Copying it to a temporary file should be simple - see [File::Temp](https://perldoc.pl/File::Temp). But I have to agree that anything that still requires 60Hz of fork/exec is going to be suboptimal.

Answer (score 1):

While it is difficult to provide a working solution in the absence of information on your environment and processes, I can make a few general suggestions, in case that would help.

I presume you are running under Windows. In that case, modifying your Perl code to control the target exe process through [Win32::Process](https://metacpan.org/pod/Win32::Process) might help. This module allows the creation, suspension, resumption and termination of Windows processes, given the process path.

A quick example, from its Meta CPAN page:

```
use Win32::Process;
use Win32;

sub ErrorReport{
    print Win32::FormatMessage( Win32::GetLastError() );
}

Win32::Process::Create($ProcessObj,
                       "C:\\winnt\\system32\\notepad.exe",
                       "notepad temp.txt",
                       0,
                       NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
                       ".")|| die ErrorReport();

$ProcessObj->Suspend();
$ProcessObj->Resume();
$ProcessObj->Wait(INFINITE);
```